# Combine multiple if statements into one

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is probably a simple solution but I am having trouble getting anything to work. Might just be the syntax.

Basically I want to merge these together so that one message box will pop up instead of 5.

```
If Me.Status_Mfg_Engineer <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "MFG Engineer has not approved"
If Me.Status_Quality <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Quality has not approved"
If Me.Status_Production <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Production has not approved"
If Me.Status_Product_Engineer <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Product Engineer has not approved"
If Me.Status_Other <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Other has not approved"
```

Comment: maybe with a few `else`?

Comment: Problem with ElseIf is if all 5 are not yet approved, only Mfg_Engineer message will trigger. So exactly what do you want to do? If you want to check all five then issue a composite message that identifies which items are not yet approved, that will get a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a single message box which summarises which agents have not approved.

```
Dim myPrompt as string
myPrompt=vbnullstring

If Me.Status_Mfg_Engineer <> "Approved" Then myPrompt= "MFG Engineer has not approved"
If Me.Status_Quality <> "Approved" Then myPrompt=myPrompt & vbcrlf & "Quality has not approved"
If Me.Status_Production <> "Approved" Then myPrompt=myPrompt & vbcrlf & "Production has not approved"
If Me.Status_Product_Engineer <> "Approved" Then myPrompt=myPrompt & vbcrlf & "Product Engineer has not approved"
If Me.Status_Other <> "Approved" Then myPrompt=myPrompt & vbcrlf & "Other has not approved" 

MsgBox _
    Title:="Missing approvals", _
    Prompt:=myPrompt, _
    Buttons:=vbOkOnly
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `If.. ElseIf .. Else`

```
If Me.Status_Mfg_Engineer <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "MFG Engineer has not approved"
ElseIf Me.Status_Quality <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Quality has not approved"
ElseIf Me.Status_Production <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Production has not approved"
ElseIf Me.Status_Product_Engineer <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Product Engineer has not approved"
ElseIf Me.Status_Other <> "Approved" Then MsgBox "Other has not approved"
End If
```

Edit 2:
Ah yes (@June7) - according to docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test all items then issue a single composite message, consider:

```
Dim strMsg As String
If Me.Status_Mfg_Engineer <> "Approved" Then strMsg = "MFG Engineer" & vbCrLf
If Me.Status_Quality <> "Approved" Then strMsg = strMsg & "Quality" & vbCrLf
If Me.Status_Production <> "Approved" Then strMsg = strMsg & "Production" & vbCrLf
If Me.Status_Product_Engineer <> "Approved" Then strMsg = strMsg & "Product Engineer" & vbCrLf
If Me.Status_Other <> "Approved" Then strMsg = strMsg & "Other" & vbCrLf
If strMsg <> "" Then MsgBox "Items not approved: " & vbCrLf & strMsg
```